# Text aligned from right to left on Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm running the Jupyter notebook from local Ubunto machine in Windows 10.
The problem is that all the text is aligned to the right side of the screen, including the menu - the "Files" tab for example is on the most right side.
It is very hard to read the text this way.

Is there a way to "convince" the Jupyter notebook to lunch as left to right language?

I tried to define the locale parameters and now everything is en_US.UTF-8.
I also tried to run the jupyter notebook from Edge and Chrome but both lunch with text aligned to the right.

I don't see this problem at other sites, but I don't think it is Jupyter specific issue.

[image of my Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hPD7.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that it was the Google Chrome setting after all. 
I needed to change the language setting so that the English will be on the top preference.

Answer (score 2):

Jupiter decide it base on browser language as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10980#issuecomment-374175103). Inside a specific notebook you can press `Ctl+Shift+f` and select `toggle rtl`